# Redirect URL in Nginx

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx

I recently migrated my website to Digital Ocean through the help of a **Server Guy**. I had good knowledge about .htacess apache rules but Nginx is realy difficult for me.

I had some files on my Wordpress site which have been deleted now. I want to permanently redirect those URLs to the homepage of my site.

Issue with the site: https://jobify.in
**Status**: Resolved

I have tried to add several codes in Nginx.conf and restarted the server but the redirection isn't taking place.

May be, I'm adding wrong codes. Kindly, help me to redirect these pages :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For permanent redirects use `return` and use if conditions for conditional redirects

[See here](https://serverfault.com/a/548602)